# WordPress on localhost redirecting to unknown ip

Tags: localhost, domain

I'm very new to WordPress development so forgive me if this question has already been covered.

I recently installed WordPress on my localhost. I wanted to access this website folder from a remote computer on a different network, however, I was facing an issue as the url automatically gets changed to localhost. For this, I found this link which gave me an idea of the problem I was facing (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816005/access-wordpress-site-from-another-machine).

However, once I changed the URL in wp-config file, a different issue arose, the localhost URL keeps on changing even from my computer to a random IP (http://117.217.93.139/foldername/) and the home page does not open (other pages open fine!). Even after I restored my original file the issue keeps on persisting.

What should I do so that my problem gets resolved? I will be able to access the website from a remote network as well as work on it on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check first your wp-config file and see is there is set any homepage url?
 if there then change if not then go to website database and edit table 'wp-options' where you find siteurl and homepage url then make them same.

You can also check the .htaccess (hidden file in root) also for redirection.

I hope check in wp-config and wp-option(table) will solve your website url issue

Thanks